# Yes / No Loop with Scanner

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a java program where the initial part is a scanner.  I need the user to enter a folder name and then the program needs to confirm.  The scanner is asking the relevant question and accepting the answer.  I then need it to confirm Y or N.  Y, the program will continue.  N, I need the code to loop back and ask the first question again.  I've searched around, and I can see a number of solution for integers, but not for text.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class webSiteGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a source folder: ");
        String sourceFolder = obj.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You have selected the folder '" + sourceFolder + "'. Are you sure (Y/N)");
        String confirmation = obj.nextLine();
        while (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(confirmation) && "N".equalsIgnoreCase(confirmation)) {
               System.out.println("Response not recognised.  Please confirm... Are you sure (Y/N)");
               confirmation = obj.next();
        }




    }

}
```

Comment: Solution for what? What's your question?

Comment: `!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(confirmation)` means `N` and `"N".equalsIgnoreCase(confirmation) also mean `N`

Answer (score 0):

The reaponce of "Y' and "N" will be stored in the `string sourceFolder`, so you just need to compare the `string sourcFolder` with Y and N.

> so your code be like:

```
int flag = 0;
    while (flag!=1){
      if(sourceFolder.equals("Y") ||   sourceFolder.equals("y")){
         //Your Code 
          flag=1;
    }else if((sourceFolder.equals("N") || sourceFolder.equals("n")){
           flag=1;
    } else{
         print("Invalid Input! Please choose  only between  Y or N ");
         flag=1;
    }

    }
```

P.S `flag` is actually used for exit the `while` condition. You can use any word instead of `flag`.

Ask if anything creates a doubt.